# Show $\displaystyle\int_0^af(x)g(x)dx\ge\int_0^af(a-x)g(x)dx$

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

> Assume $f$ and $g$ are monotonically increasing on $[0,a]$, Show that
>
> $$\displaystyle\int_0^af(x)g(x)dx\ge\int_0^af(a-x)g(x)dx$$

If I differentiate both sides w.r. to $a$ then;

$f(a)g(a)\ge f(0)g(a)$ and then integrate again gives the inequality ?

Comment: I don't think differentiating with respect to $a$ is permitted (or makes sense). Even if it does, the derivative of the RHS you obtained is not correct.

Comment: no,no,you can not differentiate the RIGHT side exactly unless you change it.

Comment: @S.B. can you say the correct form, please ?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are smooth enough then $$\left(\int_0^a f(a-x) g(x) \, dx \right)' = \int_0^a f'(a-x)g(x) \, dx + f(0) g(a).$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Use the fact that $$\left(f(x)-f(a-x)\right)\left(g(x)-g(a-x)\right) \geq 0.$$

Comment: but then $2\int f(x)g(x)\ge(\int f(a-x)g(x)+\int f(x)g(a-x))$

Comment: Are the 2 integrals on the RHS in my comment above, equal ?(with change of variables)

Comment: @derivative This is simple, you should be able to verify it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^a[f(x)-f(a-x)]g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}[f(a/2+x)-f(a/2-x)]g(a/2+x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\frac12\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}[f(a/2+x)-f(a/2-x)][g(a/2+x)-g(a/2-x)]\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\int_0^{a/2}[f(a/2+x)-f(a/2-x)][g(a/2+x)-g(a/2-x)]\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\[9pt]
&\gt0\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto a/2+x$
$(2)$: since $f(a/2+x)-f(a/2-x)$ is odd, we can replace $g(a/2+x)$ by its odd part
$(3)$: the product of two odd functions is even, so half the integral is over the positive domain
$(4)$: both $f$ and $g$ are monotonically increasing, so both factors in the last integrand are positive

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)g(x)dx<\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)g(x)dx.$$

Hence, the derivative with respect ot $a$ gives:
$$\left(\int_{0}^{a}f(x)g(x)dx\right)'<\left(\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)g(x)dx\right)'.$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$f(a)g(a)<f(0)g(a).$$

- If $g(a)\leq0$: I do not know what to do.
- If $g(a)> 0$: then $f(a)<f(0)$ which is absurd since $f$ is monotonically increasing on $[0, a]$

Therefore:
$$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)g(x)dx\geq\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)g(x)dx.$$

Comment: What prevents $g$ from being negative?

Comment: If $g$ is negative, where is the problem?

Comment: For starters, $f(a) g(a) < f(0) g(a)$ does not imply $f(a) < f(0)$.

Comment: Thanks I understand the mistake.

Comment: In general you cannot differentiate and expect inequalities to hold. E.g. In $(0,1)$, we have $x>x^2$, but obviously $1>2x$ isn't always true.

Comment: Ok. Thank you all. Should I delete this post? I have no problem if I keep it.